# Submit form continuously multiple times while user holds button pressed

Tags: jsf-2, form-submit

How can one achieve multiple form submission while the user holds the button pressed.

```
<h:commandButton value="Multiple submission" action="#{mngr.doSomething}"/>
```

Basically I just want to keep invoking mngr.doSomething method as long as i hold the button pressed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's only possible if you use `<f:ajax>` whereby you do **not** render the button itself. You can then use `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events to start and stop the rage submit by explicitly invoking the `onclick()` handler of the button and you can use `<f:ajax onevent>` to continue explicitly invoking the `onclick()` handler on successful return as long as the button appears to be still pressed.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" onmousedown="startRageSubmit(this)" onmouseup="stopRageSubmit(this)">
        <f:ajax onevent="processRageSubmit" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

*(again, when using `<f:ajax render>`, make sure that the button is not covered by the selector)*

with this JS:

```js
function startRageSubmit(button) {
    button.pressed = true;
    button.onclick();
}

function processRageSubmit(data) {
    if (data.status == "success" && data.source.pressed) {
        data.source.onclick();
    }
}

function stopRageSubmit(button) {
    button.pressed = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add javascript event listener with javascript `setInterval()` function to submit the form(with AJAX) in your desire intervals.